# wildcard in UML class diagram

Tags: java, generics, uml, wildcard

I'm trying to make a UML class diagram for my Java project. I need to use a wildcard in the arguments of some functions, but I don't know how to represent it in the UML. I didn't find anything about on google. Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [post](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/template.html), it's called parametrized type.

You can simply replace `T` with `?` to represent a wildcard.